# Multiple ViewHolders in RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

How can i use the multiple ViewHolders not inside the Recycler Adapter class but in saperate files. I also want the bind methods to be inside the ViewHolder classes.
My question is how to move the bind function inside the VIewHolder along with the itemCallback interface

Comment: `getItemViewType`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29697571/2235972

Comment: Your `ViewHolder` classes don't have to be nested in the `Adapter`. What problems are you having in moving them to separate files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create RecyclerView with multiple view type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type) multiple solutions here that OP is looking for

Comment: Here is step by step article on that "https://www.journaldev.com/12372/android-recyclerview-example"